# bot.dispatch() is not targeting cog.listener() correctly, Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am working on a music bot coded with discord.py. I just switched all the code that handled the audio into a new class so there could be a audio_handler instance per server. When I did that my dispatch message "newsong" stopped working.

The listener hook:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_newsong(self, ctx, title):
        print("New Song")
        embed = discord.Embed(
          color = discord.Color.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(name= "Bloody Music")
        embed.add_field(name= "Now Playing ", value=title, inline=True)
        await self.bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(title))
        view = mediaButtons(self)
        playMsg = await ctx.send(embed=embed,view=view)
```

The calling event:

```
self.bot.dispatch('newsong', ctx, self.music_queue[0][0]['title'])
```

There is no error being throw, it is just not working. Any help would be appreciated.

My best attempt on miminal reproductive example.

### Order of executuion setup adds bot cogs. --> Music cog is registerd

```
async def setup():
    #register the class with the bot
    await bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
    await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))
    await bot.start("CLIENT_TOKEN")

class music_cog(commands.Cog): ## Music cog registered -> awaiting commands.
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        self.server_list = {}


    @commands.command(name="play", aliases=["p","playing"], help="Plays a selected song from youtube") ## $play is typed setup audio_handler instance
    async def play(self, ctx, *args):
        if str(ctx.guild.id) in self.server_list:
            await self.server_list[str(ctx.guild.id)].play(self.server_list[str(ctx.guild.id)], ctx, *args)
        else:
            audioInstance = audio_handler(self.bot)
            self.server_list[str(ctx.guild.id)] = audioInstance
            await self.server_list[str(ctx.guild.id)].play(self.server_list[str(ctx.guild.id)], ctx, *args)


class audio_handler(commands.Cog):
    
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot): ## Setup audio_handler instance --> play song
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_newsong(self, ctx, title): ## run on_newsong is not reciving the hook dispatch. THIS IS THE PART NOT WORKING.
        print("New Song")
        embed = discord.Embed(
          color = discord.Color.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(name= "Bloody Music")
        embed.add_field(name= "Now Playing ", value=title, inline=True)
        await self.bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(title))
        view = mediaButtons(self)
        playMsg = await ctx.send(embed=embed,view=view)


    async def play_music(self, ctx): ## Play song --> Dispatch newsong hook
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']
            
            if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connected():
                self.vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()
            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])

            self.bot.dispatch('newsong', self, ctx, self.music_queue[0][0]['title']) ## Dispatch new song hook --> run on_newsong
```

This code snippet is not runnable, its a very big project and its going to be kinda hard to reproduce.

Comment: `discordpy` catchs all errors and hides them. You would have to chagen settings in `logging` to see errros. Discordpy doc: [Setting Up Logging](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html#logging-setup). OR you could use `print()` to see which part is executed. Maybe some code is not executed and it doesn't use your function, or it get problem in sode place - using `print()` you can see which line is working and which line doesn't work.

Comment: No repro with discord.py 2.0, probably with 1.7.3 as well.

Comment: @furas I setup debuging, and I do see that my dispatch is being called but it is not repsonding. Every line is working untill it gets to the hook. So i guess its not targeting the hook correctly.

Comment: @Bloody Can you include a [mcve]. That would include the file structure and every file used to reproduce this behaviour. Note: remove any code that you can (while still keeping the code runnable) and remove any credentials.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs I am not going to be able to send you runnable code snippets while cutting stuff out. Its a lot of lines of code that depend on a lot. I will try though to make the path more clear.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying to find the issue, I finialy figured out the issue and I feel so dumb. The file that I defined the event hook was not added to the bot as a Cog. So I could not use commands/listeners. Thanks to everyone for the help. I guess the reason no one had the answer is because it is a dumb mistake.

```
async def setup():
  #register the class with the bot
  await bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
  await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))
```

I changed the event hook to the music cog and it worked just fine.

I guess the moral of the story is 1. commands do not work if the file is not added to the bot as a cog. 2. no matter how long you have been debuging an issue. It still can be some stupid mistake you made.